# Finding list item root view by id

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

How to find a root view for an list item by id?

For example:

Activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/activity_root">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/activity_2">
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/activity_3">
            <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

List item layout:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/item_root">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/item_2">
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/item_3">
            <Button android:id="@+id/item_button" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I need to add some action on button click. All I have is button view. How do I get item_root view?

Comment: do you have a ListView?

Comment: Why do you need root view for that?

Comment: first learn how to create efficient layouts (RelativeLayout-FrameLayout-FrameLayout-Button), then see getView of your adapter

Comment: @nikis I want to add some animation on button click.

Comment: @pskink This is an example. I don't have these layouts in my code.

Comment: then you should declare your OnClick listener inside `getView()` method of your adapter

Comment: @Ari root item view is returned in adapter.getView()

Comment: @pskink I need item root, not list root.

Comment: @Ari yes i know: see getView()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this recursive function

```
 View getParent(View view, int targetId) {
    System.out.println(view.getId() +" == "+ targetId);
    if (view.getId() == targetId) {
        return view;
    }
    View parentView = (View) view.getParent();
    if (parentView == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return getParent(parentView, targetId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
view.getParent()
```

to find outer parent, to most outer view you need to call a few and make check control.

Comment: So loop: `View v = startView; while(v.getId() != R.id.item_root) { v = (View)v.getParent(); }`? There is nothing better?

Answer (score 0):

In onClick get the root view using the argument i.e view and call view.getRoot view but if its a list view than you can go for following but pass the activity i.e Activity.this to the adapter and find the root view like this:

```
mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

Any feedback is appreciated.